# Pseudo replicas in meta-analysis

Tags: meta-analysis

How do i control pseudo replicas in meta-analysis studies? I know I can randomize samples using Bootstrap for example, but how do I do this?
Any clarification will be most welcome!

Comment: What kind of meta-analysis, could you further detail the experiment?